# How to read a flat file and put the data to corresponding variable

Tags: c, file, tcc

I have a flat file (txt file), containing some field:

Primary key, Name, Address, Salary -separated by |
like:

```
A0001|John|New York City|12000
A0002|Daisy|New Delhi|32000
A0003|Dany|London|23000
```

..
etc

How could I develop a code to search each data in flat file when I have its primary key?
And each data of it is stored to particular variable for next purpose.

The result I want is:

```
Input the primary key: A0002

Result:
Name = Daisy
Address = New Delhi
Salary = 32000

Input the primary key:
```

Comment: Simple way is read each full-line with `fgets` into a buffer and then use `strncmp` to compare the first 4-digits for your key, and then process the full record with `sscanf` if your key is found. (or you could just `sscanf` every record and then compare the key). Dumping the assembly will tell you which is more efficient (I suspect `fgets/strncmp` will be more efficient) -- but you don't know till you check.

Comment: Of course, if you want to read the entire file into an array of struct, separating with `fgets/sscanf`, then you will have the entire database in memory in an easily searchable/sortable form.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, and I have come to this: #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 FILE *fp;
 char thestring[100];
 char primary[][6];

 printf("input primary key: ");
 scanf("%s",primary);

 fp=fopen("data.txt","r");
 if (fp==NULL) perror("Error opening file");
 else {
  if (fgets(thestring,100,fp) != NULL)
   puts(thestring);
  fclose(fp);
 }

 // Looking for the primary key
 puts("looking for A0002");
 int n;
 for (n=0; n<6; n++)
  if (strncmp (thestring[n],"A0002",5) == 0)
  {
   printf("found %s\n",thestring[n]);
  }

 return 0;
}

Comment: it compiled, but "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". What I missed?

Comment: Please post your code as an edit to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: regarding: `perror("Error opening file");`  the function: `perror()` does not exit the program, so the next statement should be: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  and wrap that `if()` code block with '{' and '}'

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s",primary); ` 1) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input to avoid any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior as '%s' always append a NUL byte to the input.

Comment: regarding: `char primary[][6];` this is defining a 2 dimension array, with NO entries in the first dimension  This is an error.  Suggest: `char primary[6];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a very basic approach that uses the flat-file for your storage and on each query, loops over the flat file attempting to match your `key` against the first field. If a match is found, simply use `sscanf` to separate the values (ignoring the 1st field using the *assignment suppression modifier* to your `sscanf` conversion specifier for that field, e.g. the `'*'`). Print the values. If the key isn't found in the file, say so as well.

Using `fgets()` for input, you can simply take input until the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a blank line for the key. (you simply check if the 1st character is `'\n'` and if so, break the loop).

You loop continually to allow multiple key queries to be made, using `rewind()` at the beginning of each loop to rewind to the beginning of the file each time.

Putting that together you could first open and **validate** your file is open for reading.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXN   64   /* if you need a constand, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC 1024   /* (don't skimp on buffer size) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    /* use filename provided as 1st argument ("flatfile.txt" by default) */
    FILE *fp = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "flatfile.txt", "r");

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
```

Now begin your continual loop that will read the `key` from the user, trim the `'\n'` from the end of the key (you don't want that as part of the comparison), and get the length of the key:

```
    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until [Enter] on empty line */
        char buf[MAXC], name[MAXN], city[MAXN], key[MAXN];
        unsigned salary, len, found = 0;

        rewind (fp);    /* rewind file to beginning */
        fputs ("\nInput the primary key: ", stdout);    /* prompt for key */
        if (!fgets (key, MAXN, stdin) || *key == '\n')  /* read key */
            break;
        key[strcspn (key, "\n")] = 0;                   /* trim '\n' */
        len = strlen(key);                              /* get key length */
```

With that information, now loop through your file reading each line into a buffer `buf` and then use `strcmp` to compare the first `len` chars with your `key`, and if there is a match, print it and set the `found` flag and break your file read loop. At the end if `found` isn't set, let the user know the key wasn't found, now do it again until the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone on the line asking for the primary key:

```
        while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {                 /* read each line */
            if (strncmp (buf, key, len) == 0) {         /* compare key */
                /* parse line into separate values, ignoring 1st key field */
                if (sscanf (buf, "%*63[^|]|%63[^|]|%63[^|]|%u",
                                name, city, &salary) == 3) {
                    printf ("\nResult:\nName = %s\nAddress = %s\n"
                            "Salary = %u\n", name, city, salary);
                    found = 1;  /* set flag indicating key found */
                    break;      /* no sense in reading rest */
                }
            }
        }
        if (!found) /* if key not found, so indicate */
            fputs ("\nResult: (not found)\n", stdout);
    }
```

All that remains is closing the input file. A complete example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXN   64   /* if you need a constand, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC 1024   /* (don't skimp on buffer size) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    /* use filename provided as 1st argument ("flatfile.txt" by default) */
    FILE *fp = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "flatfile.txt", "r");

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until [Enter] on empty line */
        char buf[MAXC], name[MAXN], city[MAXN], key[MAXN];
        unsigned salary, len, found = 0;

        rewind (fp);    /* rewind file to beginning */
        fputs ("\nInput the primary key: ", stdout);    /* prompt for key */
        if (!fgets (key, MAXN, stdin) || *key == '\n')  /* read key */
            break;
        key[strcspn (key, "\n")] = 0;                   /* trim '\n' */
        len = strlen(key);                              /* get key length */

        while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {                 /* read each line */
            if (strncmp (buf, key, len) == 0) {         /* compare key */
                /* parse line into separate values, ignoring 1st key field */
                if (sscanf (buf, "%*63[^|]|%63[^|]|%63[^|]|%u",
                                name, city, &salary) == 3) {
                    printf ("\nResult:\nName = %s\nAddress = %s\n"
                            "Salary = %u\n", name, city, salary);
                    found = 1;  /* set flag indicating key found */
                    break;      /* no sense in reading rest */
                }
            }
        }
        if (!found) /* if key not found, so indicate */
            fputs ("\nResult: (not found)\n", stdout);
    }
    fclose (fp);   /* close file */
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/flatfile.txt
A0001|John|New York City|12000
A0002|Daisy|New Delhi|32000
A0003|Dany|London|23000
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readflatfile dat/flatfile.txt

Input the primary key: A0002

Result:
Name = Daisy
Address = New Delhi
Salary = 32000

Input the primary key: A0003

Result:
Name = Dany
Address = London
Salary = 23000

Input the primary key: A0004

Result: (not found)

Input the primary key:
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Because you'll be searching through the data multiple times you want to store the data in memory in a more efficient (for searching) manner.

Also, you need to find any problems with the data and deal with them in an acceptable manner (generating error/warning messages, and either skipping faulty lines and/or refusing to use the file if its malformed).

In general; you want:

a) a way to get the raw data (e.g. as bytes) into memory. This could be broken (e.g. `fgets()`, which is broken and unusable because it depends on a default encoding of "end of line" that may be wrong); or could be a loop that does `read()` to load the entire file into a buffer, or (ideally) could be `mmap()`.

b1) a way to determine the expected character set and encoding (e.g. EBDIC, ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16LE, ...). This could be as simple as saying (e.g.) "the file must be UTF-8", and as complex as supporting many different characters sets and encodings with some scheme to auto-detect which the file used (e.g. the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in HTML).

b2) a way to determine what "end of line" is (e.g. if it's `"\n"` or `"\r\n"` or `"\r"`, which are all "standard" for different operating systems). For this it's possible to handle it automatically in a reliable way; by treating either `'\n'` or `'\r'` as "end of line" but then ignoring the next character if its the opposite (e.g. if you see `'\n'` then its the end of a line and if the next character is `'\r'` it will be ignored, and if you see `'\r'` then its the end of a line and if the next character is `'\n'` it will be ignored). Also note that "end of file" can (should) be treated as "end of last line in the file", possibly with a "no end of line found at end of file" warning.

b3) a loop that converts the raw bytes into a "standard for your program" encoding and character set, one character at a time, while detecting and handling things that are not valid for whichever encoding and character set the file used, until "end of line" (or "end of file" is reached; then calls a "process this line" function, then increments a "`line_number` variable (which will be used for error messages - e.g. so you can display an error message like "Invalid sequence of bytes for UTF-8 found on line 33" and make it easier for people to find/fix the problem in the text file.

c) a "process this line" function, which:

- splits the original string into 4 sub-strings (at the `'|'` characters), and discards leading and trailing white-space from each of the 4 sub-strings and may convert multiple whitespace characters into a single space character (e.g. so `"A0001    |  John  |\t  New       York City |12000"` becomes `"A0001"`,  `"John"`, `"New York City"` and `"12000"`). This should also handle errors - e.g. if there aren't enough `'|'` characters for the line to be valid. This function may also silently ignore empty lines and lines that only contain whitespace; and could also silently ignore everything after a special character (e.g. so you can support comments, like maybe `"A0001|John|New York City|12000   # This dude owes me money!"`).
- a set of functions to parse and validate each of the strings according to their actual requirements. For example, maybe the primary key must start with a capital letter (so you need a function that generates "Primary key is invalid (doesn't start with capital letter)" errors), and the "name" part must be less than 128 characters, and the number at the end (`"12000"`) must be within a specific range (and can/can't include commas so `"12,000"` is accepted, or has other rules, where each of the rules need their own nice descriptive error message). Note that the last function (for handling the number) will probably return an integer of some sort.
- code to allocate memory for a structure (literally a `struct my_thing { ....}`), and put the "sanity checked and parsed" data into the structure; then call an "add this structure" function.

d1) Some way of organizing the structures that is efficient for searches (which is your most common/most important/only use case). For this I'd probably use a hash table (using the primary key to generate a hash to use as an index into a table of linked lists).

d2) the "add this structure" function that adds a new structure to the hash table (or whatever it is you decided to use to organize the structures).

e) a "find this primary key" function, which uses the code you already have to sanity check and parse the user's input, then uses the code you already have to calculate a hash for the "sanity checked and parsed" primary key; then uses the hash (and the "sanity checked and parsed" primary key) to find the right structure.